# LDAP & Dynamic groups

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap, ldap-query

I try configure dynamic groups in slapd on Ubuntu 12.04. Dynamic groups worked but not filters.

LDIF files, what I use:

```
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: {1}accesslog.la
-
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: {2}auditlog.la
-
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: {3}constraint.la
-
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: {4}dynlist.la
-
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: {5}memberof.la
-
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: {6}ppolicy.la
```

for load modules. And

```
dn: olcOverlay={0}dynlist,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcDynamicList
olcOverlay: {0}dynlist
olcDlAttrSet: {0}groupOfURLs memberURL
```

for enable overlay dynamic list.

Simple search worked fine:

```
$ ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldaps://ldap.example.com/ -b cn=bookshelf,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
```

Answer:

```
dn: cn=bookshelf,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
cn: bookshelf
cn: employees
objectClass: groupOfURLs
objectClass: top
objectClass: domainRelatedObject
memberURL: ldap:///cn=employees,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
associatedDomain: none
gidNumber: 511
memberUid: am
memberUid: sk
memberUid: tk
```

But if I add filter to query nothing found:

```
$ ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldaps://ldap.example.com/ -b cn=bookshelf,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com memberUid=am
```

What should I do to get filter worked?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think they work like that. You're applying a filter to a filter.

Comment: Thank you. May be you can help with the configure Tomcat7 server with this group?

Now tomcat7 configured as:

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
      debug="99"
      connectionURL="ldap://127.0.0.1/"
      userPattern="uid={0},ou=users,dc=example,dc=com"
      roleBase="ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com"
      roleName="cn"
      roleSearch="memberUid={1}"
    />

Role-name configured in java application, and set to 'employees'. Worked like a charm. But I need use 'bookshelf' group. And with it not working. :(

Comment: That's a separate question, off topic for not only this question but this site. Try superuser or serverfault. But surely it should be memberUid={0}?